# Como faço para testar a API gateway de um projeto em microsserviços

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, docker, microsserviços

Como faço para testar a Api gateway de um projeto em microsserviços?

Configurei o ocelot.json da forma como está abaixo, e quando chamo no navegador  `/Billing` recebo o erro:

```
Ocelot.Responder.Middleware.ResponderMiddleware[0]
      requestId: 0HM69A8QLUIA0:00000005, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Error Code: ConnectionToDownstreamServiceError Message: Error connecting to downstream service, exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Este host não é conhecido. (billingapi:8002)
       ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): Este host não é conhecido.
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|283_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.DefaultConnectAsync(SocketsHttpConnectionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Ocelot.Requester.HttpClientHttpRequester.GetResponse(HttpContext httpContext) errors found in ResponderMiddleware. Setting error response for request path:/billingapi/GetFeeApp, request method: GET
```

ocelot.json:

```
{
  "Routes": [
    // Billing.API
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v1/Billing",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "billingapi",
          "Port": "80"
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/Billing",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Alguem pode me ajudar no que está errado ?

Answer (score 0):

Se os dados forem exatamente estes que você postou, o que está errado é o host, que tem que ser o endereço do domínio. Em vez de `billingapi`, deve ser algum endereço do tipo `amazon.com.br`, enfim, o endpoint da tal API.

P.S.: Não sei se estou usando os termos certos.

Comment: Estou testando via docker, o host no docker é billingapi

Comment: É, só que tem que ser um endereço de DNS ou então um IP público. Pode ser IP interno também, se for um teste interno. Conexão HTTP sobre TCP/IP só conversa com essas coisas. Sua aplicação no docker tem que ser acessível via um desses.

Comment: Posso estar falando alguma besteira sobre a configuração, que não sei como faz no docker. Mas a ideia do erro é que tentou acessar o host via HTTP e não localizou. Imagino que ele um mapeamento de endereço exposto para endereço interno da instância do docker, veja que o erro foi na porta 8002 e na configuração está 80. Tem que estar configurado algum mapeamento.

Comment: Entao se for testar local se eu passar o host como localhost tem que funcionar certo?

Comment: Talvez sim, acredito que sim, não sei.

Comment: Para funcionar com localhost será preciso mapear a porta para o host e colocar essa porta nas configurações